# How to bind span in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

```
<span id="spanNum" name="number" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:2rem;">{{randomNumberCreate()}}</span>

data:{

x:this.randomCreate()
}

methods:{

  randomNumberCreate : function(){
                  return  Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1000;

           }
}

mounted(){
this.randomNumberCreate()
}
```

This is work perfectly but I have a problem. My problem is I want to bind span value(random number) in x inside data section.

I used other function and use getElementByID but return function(){native code}. How can I bind x in data section with span value?

Comment: Can you please clearify what you are trying to do? I would try to help you, but didn´t understand what you want to bind on the `<span>`.

Comment: Span show as a number like 2345 I want to use this number. I want to define varialable and use.

Comment: <Component> 
text="my random number value"
<Component> I want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your method `randomNumberCreate()` would return a random number each time you call it, as expected. So you can´t reuse the returned number just with this method.

What you could do, and you already tried to do so, is to assign the returned number to a property. You did this here:

```
x: this.randomCreate()
```

Now you can reuse `x` in your component like this:

```
<span :id="x" name="number" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:2rem;">{{x}}</span>
```

In this case `:id="x"` will have the same random number as `{{x}}`.